# Intercepting login calls with Spring-Security-Rest plugin in Grails

Tags: rest, grails, spring-security

I am using the [spring security rest plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-rest) for Grails to provide a login mechanism for an AngularJS app. 
Login works fine, but I can't figure out how to intercept login calls, in order to store additional statistics on (invalid/valid) login attempts.

As I am quite new to Spring Security I am not familiar with it's filter chains. Is it possible to write a custom filter to intercept login calls without interfering with the plugins's mode of action or is there a better way to achieve what I want to do?

I saw that the Spring Security Rest plugin has a class called `RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler` which implements Spring Security's `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` interface. 
Can I provide a custom implementation of the class which is used by the plugin?

My configuration:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.persistent = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.failureStatusCode = 401
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.useGorm = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenDomainClassName = 'example.auth.AuthenticationToken'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenValuePropertyName = 'token'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.usernamePropertyName = 'username'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/auth/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter, -rememberMeAuthenticationFilter', // Stateless chain
    '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter', // Stateless chain
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'   // Traditional chain
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.active=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.useGorm=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.generation.useSecureRandom=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.headerName='X-Auth-Token'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.generation.useUUID=false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.active=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.endpointUrl='/auth/validate'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can provide a custom bean that implements the `RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler`. Take a look at the [API documentation](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/1.5.0.RC2/docs/gapi/grails/plugin/springsecurity/rest/RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) for the class to see what you need to implement. Then it's as simple as overriding the bean in your application context:

```
// Resources.groovy
restAuthenticationSuccessHandler(MyCustomRestAuthenticationSuccessHandler) {
  renderer = ref('accessTokenJsonRenderer')
}
```

It might also be helpful to look at the [default implementation](https://github.com/ganeshmax/blueberry-web-grails/blob/master/src/groovy/com/blueberry/security/RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler.groovy) to base yours on.